# What is the convergence property of $a_k$ when $a_{k+1} \le c_k a_k + b_k$?

Tags: mathematica

what is the convergence property of $a_k$ when $a_{k+1} \le c_k a_k + b_k$? Here, $c_k < 1$ and $b_k$ are decreasing functions of $k$.